# Do low level weapons have less effect then their damage status?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have these two weapons as seen in the image attached here.

[image: Core Dart vs Elegant Umbrage]
They both have similar damage, but it seems that only the one on the right, the *Elegant Umbrage* has a significant effect against enemies in the Thousands Cats map (right after Angle's quest part2 is finished).

My guess is that this is due to the difference in Level Requirements between these weapons and the enemies that I'm targeting. Is that true? does the level difference make the game ignore the weapon stats?

I'm further guessing that it is the same effect of diminishing damage as
a character has when the enemies' levels differences from the character itself
are too high - so in that case I've seen in the game that the enemies in fact do not receive the all the damage I am hitting them with, but instead they have some sort of an in-game-level-difference-armor-thing protecting them from the potential damage I could do to them.

(for example when my character is level 18 and the enemies are level 26, even if I am able to generate enough damage to kill a certain enemy and reduce it's suppose HP amount to 0, it still won't get all that damage and won't die)

I understand that this occurs between characters, but does this also apply to the weapon? I mean if the character has a high level (even higher then the enemy)
but holds a low level weapon, much lower then the enemy -

My Question: **Does the game still ignore the weapon's stats and grants that weapon lower damage to that particular enemy?**

Same as with the characters level difference thing?

Comment: Did you note the damage numbers you get from shooting those enemies with these guns? If you are the same level as enemies (and turn off you Badass Ranks), these pistols should do exactly 324 and 340 on body shots. Or even easier - go to Marcus', test dummies there are always of player level, IIRC.

Comment: What about this `Deals bonus elemental damage` on the right weapon?

Comment: @Nitro.de wins an "eagle eye" award :-) Of course, Bonus Elemental Damage is the culprit in this case, as it grants [80% extra damage for pistols](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/138263/33619)

Comment: @OrcJMR never played borderlands 2 so maybe a "lucky eagle eye" award is better in this case xD

Comment: In addition to having higher weapon damage, the gun on the right also has text saying it adds bonus elemental damage. It's got extra slag damage on top of everything.

Comment: In addition to all this E-tech pistol variants (darts and spikers) have special projectiles with delayed damage (projectile only explodes a second or two after it lands), which not only makes it harder to observe its true damage in the heat of battle, but also makes it much more awkward to use. In addition, E-tech pistols cannot get any critical hits, which is a significant loss of damage.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, weapon level does not contribute to damage calculation.

Weapon damage does depend on its level, and there is damage reduction based on attacker-target level difference, but weapon level is not used directly.

*With overhaul of Gearbox forums lots of information is lost due to broken links, so I hardly have anything written to prove my words. It should be trivial to test, though.*

Answer (score -1):

The level doesn't count. No the right weapon deals bonus elemental damage. See the weapon abilities.

This is the only difference between them.

Comment: This was my first thought as well, but, uhh...both weapons are slag. Where do you see corrosion?

Comment: @Alex The Umbrage has Corrosive damage and fire rate, but Fire accuracy and magazine size! :-)

Comment: No the right weapon deals bonus elemental damage.

Comment: Well, I'm glad we all agree on this.

Comment: Ionic You are correct! I noticed the sprit and sound of the 'bullet' of the right weapon and it does seem like it has that bonus explosion elemental damage even though it does not says so in it's stats. Thank you. I guess this resolves my concerns and now I know which weapon is indeed the better weapon regardless of price or level. its a darn shame :( the dart as an awesome weapon and I'm sad to let go of it.

Comment: Well nice to hear! :-) Don't bother. You'll find many good weapons during your game. :-) if you gonna try your overpowering at the end, you will need to throw all your weapons away after each run. :-D By the way, if this answers your question, you can mark it as your answer. :-)